# Valgrind invalid read on FILE*

Tags: c++, linux, valgrind, fopen

The following code, when built on ubuntu creates an executable.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void otherfunc(FILE* fout){
    fclose(fout);//Line 4
    fout = fopen("test.txt", "w");//Delete contents and create a new file//Line 5
    setbuf(fout, 0);//Line 6
}

int main() {
    FILE *fout = fopen("test.txt", "r");//Line 10
    if (fout) {
        //file exists and can be opened
        fclose(fout);//Line 13
        fout = fopen("test.txt", "a");//Line 14
        setbuf(fout, 0);
    }
    else {
        //file doesn't exists or cannot be opened 
        fout = fopen("test.txt", "a");//Line 19
    }
    
    otherfunc(fout);//Line 22
    
    fclose(fout);//Line 24
    return 0;
}
```

When run through valgrind, valgrind gives the following warnings:

> ==13569== Invalid read of size 4
>
> ==13569==    at 0x4EA7264: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:53)
>
> ==13569==    by 0x400673: main (newmain.cpp:24)
>
> ==13569==  Address 0x52042b0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 552 free'd
>
> ==13569==    at 0x4C2EDEB: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
>
> ==13569==    by 0x4EA7362: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:84)
>
> ==13569==    by 0x4005CD: otherfunc(_IO_FILE*) (newmain.cpp:4)
>
> ==13569==    by 0x400667: main (newmain.cpp:22)
>
> ==13569==  Block was alloc'd at
>
> ==13569==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
>
> ==13569==    by 0x4EA7CDC: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:69)
>
> ==13569==    by 0x400657: main (newmain.cpp:19)

Essentially, it is complaining that the `fclose(fout);` on Line 24 is closing an already freed memory that was freed on line 4 `fclose(fout);` within `otherfunc()`. But the Line 24's `fclose(fout);` is meant to close the `fopen()` performed on Line 5.

At any point in time in the code, whenever a `fclose()` is called, there is always exactly one open `fopen()`. Why is this then an invalid read as reported by valgrind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`otherfunc` takes a file pointer by value. So the value you've assigned at line 5 is lost after returning from `otherfunc` and when it returns into `main` the value of `fout` there remains unchanged. It contains a dangling file pointer value that you've closed at line 4. Therefore a call to `close` on line 24 will receive an invalid pointer.

Comment: Is there a way to bypass this problem with FILE* ? I need to pass the same file pointer (pointing to the same "text.txt" file) to multiple functions from main. Depending on conditions, the file may need to be closed, deleted and created afresh in different functions.

Comment: @Tryer Just pass file pointer by reference. Or pass a pointer to file pointer (because this seems to be actually a question about C).

Comment: @user4581301 and VTT. Yes, FILE *& in the above results in code that valgrind does not complain about. Thank you!